# Applying tags to a wav file in Python 2.7 on Windows

Tags: python, audio, wav

I have a `wav` file (`test.wav`)

I am trying to apply tags to it:

- title
- artist
- album
- year / release date

I have had no success with `pydub` or `eyed3`

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that it is hard or even impossible to add tags to WAV so I will convert the `wav` files to `mp3` files using `ffmpy` and then use `eyed3` to add the tags.